# LXC - two bridges

Tags: networking, lxc, network-bridge

I'm trying to create two different bridges to use with LXC.

I have the following configuration:

`/etc/lxc/default.conf`:

```
lxc.net.0.type = veth
lxc.net.0.link = lxcbr0
lxc.net.0.flags = up
lxc.net.0.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:xx:xx:xx

 lxc.net.0.type = veth
 lxc.net.0.link = lxcbr1
 lxc.net.0.flags = up
 lxc.net.0.hwaddr = 00:00:00:00:00:3x
```

`/etc/default/lxc-net`:

```
LXC_BRIDGE="lxcbr0"
LXC_ADDR="10.0.3.1"
LXC_NETMASK="255.255.255.224"
LXC_NETWORK="10.0.3.0/27"   LXC_DHCP_RANGE="10.0.3.20,10.0.3.30"
LXC_DHCP_MAX="10"

 LXC_BRIDGE="lxcbr1"
 LXC_ADDR="10.0.3.33"
 LXC_NETMASK="255.255.255.224"
 LXC_NETWORK="10.0.3.32/27"


 LXC_DHCP_RANGE="10.0.3.35,10.0.3.40"
LXC_DHCP_MAX="5"
```

But then it only appears one of the bridges:

```
 lxcbr1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.3.33  netmask 255.255.255.224  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    ether 00:16:3e:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If I delete the configuration of the lxcbr1 it shows the lxcbr0 (ifconfig) but with the two bridges configured it only appears the second one.

This way, only the container connected to the lxcbr1 has an IP address.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same key twice.

Try using lxc.net.0 and lxc.net.1

I'm bridge crazy.  I'm up to lxc.net.6 :D

Comment: I did that and after a while changing some configurations I can see the two bridges
But the containers connected to the lxcbr0 (ubu01 and ubu02) still don't have an IP address :(

Comment: OK, so the bridges do get addresses?  When it comes to the guests I believe it is now preferred that the containers define their own networking configuration.  That is where you'd specify DHCP.